# Angular2 async zone does not wait for observable completion

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a problem with a Angular2 unit test for a project I'm working on.

I created a mock-implementation of a service (my "production" code):

```
updatePayment(orderId?: String) {
    return Observable.of({
        approvalLink: 'http://foo.bar'
    });
}
```

and then i wrote unit tests for it:

```
it('should return an object containing an approvalLink', async(inject(
        [PaymentService],
        (service: PaymentService) => {
            service.updatePayment()
                .subscribe((data) => {                        
                  expect(data.approvalLink).toEqual('http://foo.bar/');
                });
        }
    )));
```

I put it in the async zone because as far as I understand, zone.js will wait for all async operations to finish when wrapping my call with async(). I know I could use jasmines `done()` or the `fakeAsync` zone and `tick()` but I want to get the point about `async()`.

So far, so good, this worked. The problem is that it still worked after changing my production code to this:

```
updatePayment(orderId?: String) {
    if (!orderId) {
        orderId = null;
    }

    return this.http.post('/updatePayment', {
        'orderId': orderId || ''
    })
        .map((data: any) => {
            return {
                approvalLink: data.json().approvalLink
            }
        });
}
```

I've added a `MockBackend` to my TestBed providers but I did not mock the response yet (so no `mockBackend.connections.subscribe...` yet).

But it still works. Giving it a closer look showed, that the subscribe() block is not executed at all (I guess because the Observable does never emit a value). But isn't this the sense of `async()`? What I would have expected is that this runs into a timeout because nothing happens. Or maybe the unit test never finishes. Even throwing an Expection would be OK for me, but why does it just pass the test without executing the logic although I explicitly said, that I'm doing async stuff right now?

This works and also executes the subscribe() callback:

```
fit('should get a approvalLink back', async(inject(
        [MockBackend, PaymentService],
        (mockBackend: MockBackend, service: PaymentService) => {
            mockBackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
                let response;
                response = new Response(new ResponseOptions({
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        approvalLink: 'http://foo.bar'
                    })
                }));

                connection.mockRespond(response);
            });

            service.updatePayment()
                .subscribe((data) => {
                    expect(data.approvalLink).toEqual('http://foo.bar');
                });
        }
    )));
```

Again - I know how I could solve the problem but maybe someone can give me some insight that helps me understand what that async zone is about then...

Thanks in advance,
David